# How to use lists with the Haskell singletons library?

Tags: haskell, singleton-type

I'm trying to make a type using the [`singletons`](https://github.com/goldfirere/singletons) library where I use a list:

```
import Data.Singletons.TH (singletons)

$(singletons [d|

    data LLVMType
        = IntegerType
        | FloatType
        | FunctionType { argumentTypes :: [LLVMType] }

    |])

foo :: SLLVMType ('FunctionType '[ 'IntegerType ])
foo = ???
```

I tried to make `foo` be: `SFunctionType [SIntegerType]`, however it results in this error:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘Data.Singletons.Sing '['IntegerType]’
              with actual type ‘[Data.Singletons.Sing 'IntegerType]’
• In the first argument of ‘SFunctionType’, namely ‘[SIntegerType]’
  In the expression: SFunctionType [SIntegerType]
  In an equation for ‘foo’: foo = SFunctionType [SIntegerType]
```

How do I make an expression for `foo` that typechecks? Or how can I achieve this in another way?

[Github repo with the code](https://github.com/CRogers/singleton-list-question).

Comment: Next time you're using Template Haskell that expands into code that needs other extensions, it would be helpful if you'd list those at the top. Otherwise people answering your question will have to work out which extensions they need first.

Comment: dfeuer: Understood, but I did also post a github repo with all the code ready to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're very close, but you need to use list *singletons*.

```
{-# language TemplateHaskell, DataKinds, GADTs, TypeFamilies #-}
module SingList where

import Data.Singletons.TH (singletons)
import Data.Singletons.Prelude.List (Sing (SNil, SCons))

$(singletons [d|

    data LLVMType
        = IntegerType
        | FloatType
        | FunctionType { argumentTypes :: [LLVMType] }

    |])

foo :: SLLVMType ('FunctionType '[ 'IntegerType ])
foo = SFunctionType (SCons SIntegerType SNil)
```

Comment: Thanks! Wondered why I didn't see this in the [docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-2.3.1/docs/Data-Singletons-Prelude-List.html), looks like I was looking at the [promotion docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-2.3.1/docs/Data-Promotion-Prelude-List.html) for list instead!